# Variable length dimension in tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement the paper "End-to-End memory networks" (http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08895)

Each training example consists of a number of phrases, a question and then the answer. The number of sentences is variable, as is the number of words in each sentence and the question. Each word is encoded as an integer. So my input would have the form [batch size, # of sentences, # words in sentence].

Now my problem is that the second and third dimension are unknown for each mini-batch. Can I still somehow represent this input as a single tensor or do I have to use lists of tensors, so that I have a list of length batch_size, and then a sublist of length number of sentences and then for each sentence a tensor, whose size is also not known in advance, corresponding to the words encoded as integers.

Can I use this second approach or will tensorflow then not be able to backpropagate, e.g. I have an operation where I have to calculate the following sum: \sum_i tf.scalar_mul(p_i, c_i), where p_i is a scalar and c_i is an embedding vector that was previously calculated. The tensors for the p and c values are then stored in a list, so I would have to sum over the elements in the two lists in a loop. I'm assuming that tensorflow would not be able to incoorporate this loop in the computation graph, correct? I'm sceptical since theano has a special scan function that allows one to loop over input, so I'm assuming that a regular loop would cause problems in the computation graph. How does tensorflow handle this?

Comment: TensorFlow has `scan`. Also dimensions can be dynamic like in Theano

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question though: If I use dynamic dimensions on a placeholder of shape [None, None, None], and I want to flatten it out, so that I can call embedding_lookup on every element in that tensor and then want to reshape that result into the original form, how can I do that if I declared the dimensions as dynamic?

Comment: tf.reshape accepts dynamic dimensions, ie tf.reshape(tf.constant(np.ones((2,3))), tf.shape(tf.constant(np.ones((3,2)))))

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't understand your example. Here's my problem, I have a placeholder variable x_in = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = [None, None, None]) and I want to embed each element in x_in using the embedding tensor: A = tf.get_variable(name = 'A', shape = [V,d]). So I call embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(A,tf.reshape(x_in, [-1])), now if I want to reshape embeddings to the shape of x_in but with a fourth dimension, corresponding to the embedding depth d. How can I do that, given that I don't know the values for the first three dimensions?

Comment: you can get the values of first three dimensions using tf.shape

Answer (score 0):

Moving Yaroslav's comment to an answer:

TensorFlow has [`tf.scan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan). Dimensions may also be dynamic as in Theano.